# Macro for NSLocalizedString

Tags: objective-c, macros, nslocalizedstring

All my calls of NSLocalizedString have nil as second param, because i don't use any comments. But i hate to repeat myself. Now i'm asking myself if it's ok to define a macro like LSSTRING(str) that calls NSLocalizedString(str, nil), and if so how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can. Add the following macro to your pre-compiled header. ie., in {ProjectName}-Prefix.pch file

```
#define LSSTRING(str) NSLocalizedString(str, nil)
```

Comment: One problem with this approach is that genstrings expects to find a string for the comment, and will give an error like this: `Bad entry in file ... (line = #): Argument is not a literal string.`

Comment: In Xcode, just do a find/replace like this:

Find: LSSTRING\((@\"\w+\")\)
Replace: NSLocalizedString\(\1, \1\)

Answer (score 2):

im using

```
#define _(format, ...) [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:format, ##__VA_ARGS__]] value:@"" table:nil]
```

Comment: Why the first `stringWithFormat:` ?